# CSS rotate animation only working in Webkit

Tags: animation, css

I want to have a element rotating 360 degrees infinitely. Here is my code:

```
.rotate-animation {
  -webkit-animation: rotate 2s linear 0 infinite normal;
  -moz-animation: rotate 2s linear 0 infinite normal;
  -o-animation: rotate 2s linear 0 infinite normal;
  -ms-animation: rotate 2s linear 0 infinite normal;
  animation: rotate 2s linear 0 infinite normal;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);

  }
  to { 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes rotate {
  from {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);

  }
  to { 
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes rotate {
  from {
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);

  }
  to { 
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes rotate {
  from {
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);

  }
  to { 
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);

  }
  to { 
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

It works only in Webkit browsers. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to define seconds with zero `0s` also. like this:

```
-moz-animation: rotate 2s linear 0s infinite normal;
```

Instead of this

```
-moz-animation: rotate 2s linear 0 infinite normal;
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/srxzF/2/

Comment: And apparently this is the correct behavior. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=653999

Answer (score 0):

In purpose for more safety the better choise is write seconds with **s** in all cases.

```css
rotate 2s linear 0s infinite normal;
```